# Can I remove the dotted focus rectangle over tabs on a TabControl?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, focus, tabcontrol

I have a tab control and need to remove the dotted focus rectangle around the selected tab.

I have set the TabStop property of the TabControl to false. However if I click on a tab and press the `Tab` key, the dotted rectangle appears around the tabname.

I have tried creating my own `TabControl` and tried this

```
class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
        public MyTabControl()
        {
            TabStop = false;
            DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(DoMoreTabControl_DrawItem);
            Invalidate();
        }
}
```

However, the dotted rectangle still appears.

I also tried overriding the `MyTabControl.OnPaint()` method but it doesn't help.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to hide it? Any compelling reason?

Answer (score 5):

Set the focus to tab instead of header (like this)

```
private void tabControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TabControl).SelectedTab.Focus();
}
```

You will see dotted rectangle for a millisecond, as soon as the above event gets executed it will disappear.

Also, to remove dotted rectangle for default selected tab on load

```
private void tabControl1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TabControl).SelectedTab.Focus();
}
```

Both this changes worked for me!
hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, DrawItem event.  You didn't post it, impossible to guess what's wrong with it.  Just make sure that you don't call `e.DrawFocusRectangle()`, likely to present when you copied the MSDN sample code.  Simply deleting the statement is sufficient.  Consider using a different background color or text font style as an alternative so the focus hint isn't entirely lost.

Comment: A good example of an application that does this: Visual Studio and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Also web browsers. There is no focus rectangle on the tabs. Ctrl+tab appears to the accepted way to navigate tabs from the keyboard.