# How to remove dotted focus rectangle from tab control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, focus, tabcontrol

I'm trying to remove dotted focus rectangle from my custom `Tab Control`. I've tried everything and I could not remove that rectangle.

[image: Tab Control Dialog]

As you can see in the picture, the focus rectangle is disturbing in my application design.

Please help!

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216764/can-i-remove-the-dotted-focus-rectangle-over-tabs-on-a-tabcontrol

Comment: Yep, It didn't worked for me.

Comment: The focus rectangle shows up during run time and not just at design time?

Comment: Show us the drawing code!

Comment: @mickey: No it doesn't. you can see how clearly, albeit ugly,  the selected tab is marked. Neither VS nor Firefox nor Thunderbird shows it. The FocusRectangle on tabs is outdated.

Comment: The focus rectangle shows during the run and the design time :(

I do not find any solution to fix it.

Comment: __Show us the drawing code__! ! ! !

Comment: I already have fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: I know I am late to the party, but can you explain how you fix it I have the same issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the focus cue, you have to set `UserPaint` to true, and then paint the entire tab control yourself, including the borders, text, backgrounds, highlighting, hot-tracking, etc.

The following code only paints the tab text and the background:

```
public class TC2 : TabControl {
    public TC2() {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var g = e.Graphics;

        TabPage currentTab = this.SelectedTab;
        for (int i = 0; i < TabPages.Count; i++) {
            TabPage tp = TabPages[i];
            Rectangle r = GetTabRect(i);
            Brush b = (tp == currentTab ? Brushes.LightSteelBlue : Brushes.LightGray);
            g.FillRectangle(b, r);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, tp.Text, tp.Font, r, tp.ForeColor);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaintBackground(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: My custom tab control already does this. Even with a custom paint still appears the focus rectangle. I do not know what to do :(

Comment: `DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` does not equal `SetStyle(UserPaint)`. At this point, you have to provide some code, otherwise it's guessing.

Comment: @Loathing +1. I needed this.